Is Matthew 22 a parable, prophecy, or both
Commonly Matthew 22 is taken as a prophecy for the destruction of Jerusalem and preaching to the gentiles, but one thing I noticed is the "wedding" isn't opened to the guests until after the city is destroyed.
Matthew 22:7-10 (ESV)

The king was angry, and he sent his troops and destroyed those
murderers and burned their city. 8 Then(τότε) he said to his servants, ‘The
wedding feast is ready, but those invited were not worthy. 9 Go
therefore to the main roads and invite to the wedding feast as many as
you find.’ 10 And those servants went out into the roads and gathered
all whom they found, both bad and good. So the wedding hall was filled
with guests.

If this were a prophecy this would mean the kingdom of Heaven will only be opened to the gentiles after the city (Jerusalem) is destroyed, but that would contradict later passages in that explicitly show the kingdom being opened before the city (Jerusalem) is destroyed.
Matthew 28:19-20 (ESV):

Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in[b]
the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, 20
teaching them to observe all that I have commanded you. And behold, I
am with you always, to the end of the age.”

So why is the wedding parable typically taken as prophecy? (This would also cover the parable of the tenants for the same reason)

If it is not a prophecy of the destruction of Jerusalem, then your question doesn't exist.

@VincentWong My question is to those who take it as a prophecy.

Jesus's InterpretationIn many, if not most, Jesus interpreted His parables himself. Although sometimes He took Hs disciples aside to reveal the meaning privately.
As was already noted, the parable in question did not end with verse 10, but continued to verse 13 And then Jesus gave the meaning of the parable: "For many are called, but few are chosen".
There is no difficulty in chronology when one considers that Jesus---after dealing with the rebellious Jews---starts over, and deals with the other nations (Gentiles) who misbehave as well. Both sections end in Judgment (vs. 7, vs. 13) The first section ends with the Destruction of a City, and the second section dealt with casting into outer darkness.
Truly this passage is a prophetic warning to both Jew and Gentile. Take heed to the calling of God in your lives.  Don't take it lightly; there are eternal consequences---and sometimes immediate physical consequences too! (Some men's sins are evident now, and some are revealed later.)

It is both a parable and a prophecy, as with many parables but not all of them. It should be noted that the parable does not end with vs. 10:

11 But when the king came in to meet the guests he saw a man there not
dressed in a wedding garment. 12 He said to him, ‘My friend, how is it
that you came in here without a wedding garment?’ But he was reduced
to silence. 13 Then the king said to his attendants, ‘Bind his hands
and feet, and cast him into the darkness outside, where there will be
wailing and grinding of teeth.’ 14 Many are invited, but few are
chosen.”

This is apparently a reference to the teaching that spiritual purity is required of those who participate in the messianic wedding feast. This is also expressed in Revelation 7:14 where those who "wash their robes and make them white" have survived the tribulation and Rev. 19:9, where "the [white] linen represents the righteous deeds of the holy ones."
The OP asks: "So why is the wedding parable typically taken as prophecy?" This is because the early church read this parable in light the destruction of Jerusalem in 70 c.e. - as fulfillment of the prediction that the king would destroy "their city."

But isn't out of order? as the king destroys the city then sends his officials out to the "streets", but in reality it was in the opposite order.
